# Android studio version 3 compilation Gradle error

Tags: android

When I open a project in `Android` studio, it's giving me an error of `Gradle`. What is the problem and what is the solution? 
This is my message:

> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException:
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:918)

... the message is long

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and finally i resolved it!

1. Close Android studio
2. Delete system-root/.gradle/cashes folder
3. Delete your-project/app/build folder
4. Rerun project

After syncing with gradle all files will download properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please synchronize with

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
```

Comment: Please how can I synchronize with 

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

Comment: I test it but it give me an other error


Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.jar
Required by:
    project :  .........

Comment: can you please post your app gradle file and Project gradle file.

Comment: you mean this .. 
`code`
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.phoneonservo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 14
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
}

`code`

Comment: compileSdkVersion and support library should be same...please change compileSdkVersion to 18.sync it now go to the app gradle. there you can find suggestion for classpath change it n sync...i think it will fix ur problem

Comment: when I sync it , give the same error  ,' code ' Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2.